# Docker Containers are not coming up after host reboot

Tags: docker

Docker containers are not coming up after host crash or reboot. We see volume unmount errors in docker logs. This issue is not happening frequently it is happening sporadically.

We had to delete containers and recreate them to make it work which is impacting our environment. Please let us know if there is any way to avoid this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Use `--restart unless-stopped` option in `docker run` command.

For more information [Restart policies (`--restart`)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies---restart)

Comment: We are already using restart policy on failure. Issue is docker containers not coming up after host reboot. This is happening sporadically not always. We see some volume unmount errors in docker daemon logs when the issue is happening.

Comment: dockerd-current[3429]: time="2018-09-24T16:01:48.522966047+05:30" level=error msg="Failed to start container d57a864ff1579b631611520239f61f17058299645da1245e1ae800a1d91fcf0b: error creating overlay mount to /var/lib/docker/overlay2/e5d1925fd2e3f2e9cf2aa726c89734daa9ece4897fd4717d3b32577105aa30f5/merged: invalid argument"

Comment: will you share the command you used to run the docker container ?

Comment: docker run -e \"TZ=Asia/Kolkata\" -v /opt/logs/config/log4j2.xml:/opt/EAP-6.4.0/standalone/configuration/log4j2.xml -v /opt/deployment/cfkg/certs:/opt/deployment/cfkg/certs -d --name=<container name> --restart on-failure:5 -it -d <image name>:<version> <script to be executed>

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved after enabling selinux on host.